# file name is variable - does not write to file

Tags: python, file

I have a large file about some populations (columns and rows). And I want to read the file and extract some information and write a script to create a single file for each population.

The issue now when I want to write to each population file "variable name"
just **the last row** of the large file is written to the correct population. **Other files are empty**. When I try to print to the terminal, it prints the data correctly.

*The files are already created in a previous part in the code.

Any suggestions?

```
for item in d: # d is a set to hold the populations names
    filename= item # hold the file name
    if item == 'population': # exclude the header of the column
        continue
    elif item== pop:
        with open(filename+'.txt', 'a') as f: # add to the specific population file
            f.write(str(fID) +" "+ sID)  # write the two columns to the file
```

Comment: you should try adding some print messages to see if what you expect to happen is actually happening at all ...

Comment: can you tell us what the variable pop is? Maybe it's ment to be String?!

Comment: Please use the correct comment characters for the language. It is disorienting to see C++ comments in a Python code example.

Comment: For each line (person), the script is reading the population as pop. If the name of the population is new, it will be added to the set.  The code above is part from the main loop (reading the files).

Comment: What is the purpose of `elif item== pop`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will write a file only when the name stored in 'item' is the same as the one stored in 'pop'. Probably you want to generate several files so the code, maybe, should be:

```
if item == 'population': # exclude the header of the column
    continue
else:
    with ...
```